# How can I return an array of promises in a then statement

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, protractor, deferred

So for the past few hours I've been looking into async stuff and using promises. I'm using the testing framework protractor, and theres a few async things I'm having trouble with.

In this save function, I call cm.org1.all() asynchronously, and use then to get the response. I loop over the response, and I need call getNewElement() to each element in the response, which also has an async call in it, so each returns a promise.

So I have this array of promises, but I don't know how to return it. The return of cm.save() is []. I need it to be ['foo',foo',foo',foo']

This code below doesn't work, but it's what I have so far.

```
 var cm = companyManagement() {
    //whatever is initialized below is initialized up here

    this.save = function() {
        cm.saveButton.click(); 
        var elements;
        var promises = [];
        var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        cm.org1.all(by.repeater('brand in vm.brands'))
        .then(function(response) {
            //elements is of length 4
            elements = response;
            for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++) {
                promises.push(getNewElement(elements, i));
            }
            //defer.fulfill(promises); not correct?
        });
        return protractor.promise.all(promises); //not correct?
    };

    function getNewElement(elements, i) {
         var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        var alias = elements[i].element(by.binding('brand.alias'));
        alias.getText().then(function(aliasText) {
            defer.fulfill('foo');
        });
        return defer.promise;
    }
}
    cm.save()
    .then(function(response){
       console.log("my new array is",response);
    });
```

Comment: No, it doesn't matter to me what promises I use, protractor or native. @DominicTobias

Comment: Ok, and do you want to return an array of promises, or wait for all promises to complete before continuing after calling save?

Comment: in general, promise.all returns one promise, which will be resolved, when all provided to it promises will be resolved, just try `console.log(arguments)` should be 4 results here..

Comment: @DominicTobias I want to wait for all promises to be done before continuing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with protractor promises manually in your tests is usually a sign of overcomplicating a problem. `Protractor` has a variety of abstractions and functional programming tools that cover most of the use cases.

You can solve it in just a single line if you would use repeater's [`.column()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater):

```
this.save = function() {
    cm.saveButton.click(); 
    return cm.org1.all(by.repeater('brand in vm.brands').column('brand.alias')).getText();
};
```

---

> I would do this, but I want to eventually be able to get the element's parent, if the column brand.alias matches with a certain constant I have. if I only have the alias text I couldn't be able to get the parent, correct me if I'm wrong.

[`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) and [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) to the rescue:

```
cm.org1.all(by.repeater('brand in vm.brands').column('brand.alias')).filter(alias) {
    return alias.getText().then(function (aliasText) {
        return aliasText === "foo";
    });
}).map(function (alias) {
    return alias.element(by.xpath("..")).getText();  // getting the parent
});
```

Comment: I would do this, but I want to eventually be able to get the element's parent, if the column brand.alias matches with a certain constant I have. if I only have the alias text I couldn't be able to get the parent, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: brb I'll try this out and get back to you

Comment: okay, this works for the most part! thanks. I'm a little confused on what element(by.xpath) returns for the parent. It doesn't look like a normal protractor element, it looks like this. http://jsfiddle.net/9cepxear/ normally I would do something like getInnerHtml or getText, but those are undefined here. I remember trying this xpath thing yesterday before I did any of this, so I don't think it has to do with this specific use case

Comment: @JarlCohnson interesting, could you try resolving the result of the `save()` function call and see what is printed now (I've added `getText()` call)?..

Comment: I guess I don't really understand if I should get the return of `cm.save()` with just using `var x = cm.save()` or `cm.save().then(function(ret){var x = ret;})`. 
When I use the latter on the original (without map including getText), it just waits in the terminal on nothing. When the former, it dumps out what I have in that fiddle.

Anyway, with `getText()` in the map function, it returns `Array [ 'foo-alias\nView' ]`. (foo-alias is my constant).

Comment: @JarlCohnson thanks, it looks like it returns what it is supposed to return - the text of a specific brand alias's parent text..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
this.save = function() {
    cm.saveButton.click(); 
    var elements;
    var promises = [];
    var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
    return cm.org1.all(by.repeater('brand in vm.brands'))
    .then(function(response) {
        //elements is of length 4
        elements = response;
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length;i++) {
            promises.push(getNewElement(elements, i));
        }
        return protractor.promise.all(promises);
    });
};
```

Comment: cm.save() returns undefined because the return is in the then() statement

Comment: Did you notice that I return "cm.org1.all()"?