# How can I return an array of Promises from a then clause

Tags: promise, es6-promise

I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921760/how-can-i-return-an-array-of-promises-in-a-then-statement) which doesnt solve my problem. I am trying to run a cron job every 10 hours that lets me get the categories first and then based on the categories, i find the information for each category. How can I simplify the below Promise. I am NOT using Bluebird or Q, this is the native JS promise. Honestly, the code below looks like the same callback hell Promises were supposed to avoid, any suggestions

```
flipkart.getAllOffers = function () {
    interval(43200, () => {
        flipkart.findAllCategories()
            .then((categories) => {
                flipkart.save('flipkart_categories.json', categories)
                if (categories) {
                    for (let item of categories) {
                        flipkart.findAllForCategory(item.category, item.top)
                            .then((items) => {
                                flipkart.save('flipkart_top_' + item.category + '.json', items)
                            }).catch((error) => {
                                console.log(error)
                            })
                    }
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    })
}

function interval(seconds, callback) {
    callback();
    return setInterval(callback, seconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: First off, you're using a lot more indent than is needed.  By putting `.then()` handlers at yet another level of indent, you're accumulating a lot more indent than needed.  That's a personal style thing, but isn't needed and creates a lot more indent than is required for simple reading of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stop using an extra level of indent just for `.then()`, then you have a pretty simple structure.

One `.then()` handler that contains
an `if()` statement
that contains a for loop
that contains another async operation

In this modified version, half your indent comes from your `if` and `for` which has nothing to do with promises.  The rest seems very logical to me and doesn't at all look like callback hell.  It's what is required to implement the logic you show.

```
flipkart.getAllOffers = function () {
    interval(43200, () => {
        flipkart.findAllCategories().then((categories) => {
            flipkart.save('flipkart_categories.json', categories)
            if (categories) {
                for (let item of categories) {
                    flipkart.findAllForCategory(item.category, item.top).then((items) => {
                        flipkart.save('flipkart_top_' + item.category + '.json', items)
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                        throw error;     // don't eat error, rethrow it after logging
                    });
                }
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
}
```

If `flipkart.save()` is also async and returns a promise, then you probably want to hook those into the promise chain too.

---

You can always create a helper function that may improve the look also like this:

```
flipkart.getAllOffers = function () {
    interval(43200, () => {
        flipkart.findAllCategories().then(iterateCategories).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    })
}

function iterateCategories(categories) {
    flipkart.save('flipkart_categories.json', categories);
    if (categories) {
        for (let item of categories) {
            flipkart.findAllForCategory(item.category, item.top).then((items) => {
                flipkart.save('flipkart_top_' + item.category + '.json', items);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }    
}
```

If  you're trying to collect all the results (something your title implies, but your question doesn't actually mention), then you can do this:

```
flipkart.getAllOffers = function () {
    interval(43200, () => {
        flipkart.findAllCategories().then(iterateCategories).then((results) => {
            // all results here
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })
}

function iterateCategories(categories) {
    flipkart.save('flipkart_categories.json', categories);
    let promises = [];
    if (categories) {
        for (let item of categories) {
            let p = flipkart.findAllForCategory(item.category, item.top).then((items) => {
                flipkart.save('flipkart_top_' + item.category + '.json', items);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            promises.push(p);
        }
    }
    // return promise here that collects all the other promises
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Added a couple more versions to show a different coding style and to show collecting all the results.

Comment: thank you very much for all your suggestions , i wont be able to use Promise.all since some of them may fail sometimes if the url expires and Promise.any simply resolves without checking if all are done, Promise. settle from bluebird doesnt seem to be present in native es6 promises :)

Comment: @PirateApp - The way either of the last two code blocks work, any promise rejection is caught and handles BEFORE it gets to `Promise.all()` so that is not an issue.  If you have a `.catch()` handler and you don't return a rejected promise or throw from within it, then the promise rejected is considered "handled" and the state changes to resolved.  Since both those last two have the internal `.catch()` that logs it and they don't rethrow, `Promise.all()` will only see resolved promises.  You should be fine.